# send html in an email via php, can't seem to do it

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a list of subscribers who I am trying to send a HTML type email to (essentially a news letter). But currently, it is just sending plainly and I can't seem to figure how to make it look better.

I've searched through other questions but can't seem to apply the answers to my own code, so could someone help? Code is shown below:

```
<?php

$user = "example"; 
$password = "example"; 
$host = "example"; 
$dbase = "example"; 
$table = "example"; 

$from= 'example';//specify here the address that you want email to be sent from

$subject= $_POST['subject'];
$body= $_POST['body'];

// Connection to DBase 
$dbc= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password, $dbase) 
or die("Unable to select database");

$query= "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result= mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) 
or die ('Error querying database.');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$firstname= $row['firstname'];
$lastname= $row['lastname'];
$email= $row['email'];

$msg= "Dear $firstname $lastname,\n$body";
mail($email, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
echo 'Email sent to: ' . $email. '<br>';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

So I have a message box where I can type a message but how would I make that message box, html style? So I can add in  H2 etc tags? Or just make the email like a html newsletter

- I have put example in on purpose

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to set your headers as `text/html`

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and pass that to your `mail()` function.

Something like this..

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

---

#### Your Modified Code

```
$msg= "<h3>Dear $firstname $lastname</h3>,<br><br><b>$body</b>"; //<-- Added some basic formatting
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Yourname <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

**Refer** : [`PHP Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples)

Comment: where would I add the above in? as in where abouts on the php

Comment: Please see the 4th example on this link. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples

Comment: Don't forget to add boundaries also so non-html e-mail clients know what to do also.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work, doesn't do anything

Comment: Manual didn't work? I don't think so. Can you post the code what you have tried on the question ?

Comment: Pre-defined HTML templates ?

Comment: You can have a look at this.. http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ However, there are many tools available , you just need to google out there for `php email templates` something like that.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help, I'll mark as accepted answer but can't do it right now for some reason so i'll try to do it later

Answer (score 1):

You need to send headers with html declared: example

```
$to = 'person@example.com';

$subject = 'Your subject';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: you@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = // your html code here


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Mailer Class instead of mail()

```
$mail  = new PHPMailer();// defaults to using php "mail()"

$mail->SetFrom("frommail");
    $mailAdmin->AddAddress("tomail");   
    $mailAdmin->Subject = $subject;                 
    $mailAdmin->MsgHTML($message);
    $mailAdmin->IsHTML(true);
    $mailAdmin->Send();
```

You just need to include a class file phpmailer class file wich can be downloaded online.